# Determining the integers / lines between two given integers / lines

Tags: r, read-text

I have a large body of text that I am working with in r and I have identified the line numbers containing key text. I have these stored as two different objects: location1 and location2

I want to now create a list of the lines that fall between location1 and location2.

```
location1  int [1:393] 4 21 38 57 75 93 110 127 144 166 ...
location2  int [1:393] 6 23 41 59 77 95 112 129 147 168 ...
```

So I am looking for output that looks like:

```
5 22 39 40 58 76 111 128 145 146 167
```

This is more complicated than just location1 + 1 because there are instances where there are multiple lines between `location1` and `location2`. For example, when `location1` is 38 and `location2` is 41 I would expect to get 39 and 40 in the output.

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: No, because sometimes there are multiple lines between the two locations

Comment: Can you please add those cases and expecteed output so that it becomes clear

Comment: I'm sorry your solution didn't work for me when I tried to run it

Comment: It is running fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 unlist(Map(seq, location1 + 1, location2 - 1))
 [1]   5  22  39  40  58  76  94 111 128 145 146 167
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Map`

```
unlist(Map(`:`, location1 + 1, location2 - 1))
#[1]   5  22  39  40  58  76  94 111 128 145 146 167
```

---

Or a `Vectorize`d approach with `rep`

```
v1 <- location2 - location1 -1
rep(location1, v1) + sequence(v1)
#[1]   5  22  39  40  58  76  94 111 128 145 146 167
```

---

Or using `map2`

```
library(purrr)
map2(location1 + 1, location2 - 1, `:`)
```

which can also be changed as

```
tmp <- sweep(df11 , 2,c(1, -1), `+`)

do.call(Map, c(f = `:`, unname(tmp)))
```

#### data

```
location1 <- c(4, 21, 38, 57, 75, 93, 110, 127, 144, 166)

location2 <- c(6, 23, 41, 59, 77, 95, 112, 129, 147, 168)
df1 <- data.frame(location1, location2)
```